# Where to install pip packages inside my Conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda

As I understand it, if I use pip install ___, that package will go to my global version of python. If I change directory to the within my Conda environment then that package will be isolated within the environment. Is this correct?

I have searched to try and find where to put the pip packages (within my Conda environment). It used to be that you would install the pip packages in `/Anaconda3/envs/venv_name/bin/`. It appears the `bin` folder is now located within the Library folder, like this: `/Anaconda3/envs/venv_name/Library/bin`. Is the `bin` folder still the recommended place to put the packages installed by pip?

In other words should I be placing the pip installed packages here: `/Anaconda3/envs/venv_name/Library/bin` ?

Comment: Are you aware about `--user` option? Do you know about `pipenv`?

Answer (score 17):

## No Specification Needed

Fortunately, one need not manually specify where to install the packages. Instead, if one uses the `pip` associated with the environment, packages will install to the `site-packages` directory of environment's `python` by default.

#### Example

```
 > conda activate venv_name
 
 # check that you are using the right pip
 > which pip
 /Anaconda3/envs/venv_name/bin/pip  # should be something like this

 > pip install <package name>
```

This will install packages into `/Anaconda3/envs/venv_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`, or whatever Python version you have installed for the environment.

> ⛔️ **Important Note**: There are some flags for `pip install` that change this behavior, most notably the `--user` flag. Conda users are strongly discouraged from using this flag because it installs packages at a user-level, leading to packages being visible to other environments with matching Python versions (major+minor).

## Caution: Mixing PyPI and Conda Packages

Be aware that (as @WilliamDIrons pointed out), it is usually preferable to use `conda install -n venv_name <package name>` instead of `pip`. The common practice is to only use `pip` in a Conda environment when the package is not available through a Conda repository. It is strongly recommended to read and follow the best practices found in the "[*Using pip in an environment*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env)" documentation.

Comment: To add to the answer, whenever possible use conda install <package name> instead of pip install <package name> to install the conda version of the package.

Comment: @NickT, `which pip` is just to show you that you can check which copy of pip you are about to run in the actual command (`pip install <package name>`). You don't have to run that. I only included it because sometimes people have conda envs that don't have `pip` installed. If that is the case, you should install it via `conda install pip`.  Otherwise, you might inadvertently use your system's `pip` and wonder why you can't find your packages.